# constraints on basis of tag value in xsd

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I have to create constraints on below xml on basis of its tag value

```
<struct>
<member>
<name>Identifier</name>
<value><i4>11002</i4></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>StartDate</name>
<value><dateTime.iso8601>20160701T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601>      
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>Type</name>
<value><i4>0</i4></value>
</member>
</struct>
```

The xsd format that i have created is like,it is just the short form of code and generated using a tool online.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="struct">
    <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="member">
                <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string" />
                         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value">
                         <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="string" type="xs:string" />
                            </xs:sequence>
                         </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

What i need is to put constraint on startDate that it is of correct format.
and identifier is only 5 to 10 digits long.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML design is excessively meta and is thereby frustrating your ability to express constraints on data values using XSD 1.0.

You can do one of the following:

1. Redesign your XML to use concrete tag names such as `Identifier`, `StartDate` etc.
2. Constrain `i4` and `dateTime.iso8601` apart from `name`.
3. Use XSD 1.1 assertions to enforce checking based upon the value of
   `name`.

Recommend you choose #1.